# how to excute some lines when a black screen is on?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UI animation for a black screen that fades in (goes from transparent to black) and another that fades out (goes from black to transparent). I'm trying to play the fade-in animation (screen becomes black) and then execute some lines of code while the screen is still black and then play the fade-out screen.

I tried to achieve this using `StartCoroutine(Text());` like so:

```
    transitionAnim.Play("fade_in");
    StartCoroutine(Text());
    character.SetActive(false);
    Damagedcharacter.SetActive(true);
    transitionAnim.Play("fadeout");

 IEnumerator Text()  //  <-  its a standalone method
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
```

I want these lines:

```
character.SetActive(false);
Damagedcharacter.SetActive(true);
```

to be executed during the black screen. but they are not. what happens is that they are executed first then the black screen fade in and out.

How can I make the black screen stays for a while and execute some lines during the black screen and then fade out?

Comment: _[Why coroutines are evil](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2022/10/06/implementing-time-based-delays-in-unity-3d/)_.

Comment: `await Task.Delay()` is the contemporary way to do things...and is much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Coroutine doesn't magically delay the code in the method it is started from.

Either move your lines to the end of the `IEnumerator` like

```
transitionAnim.Play("fade_in");
StartCoroutine(Text());


IEnumerator Text()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    character.SetActive(false);
    Damagedcharacter.SetActive(true);
    transitionAnim.Play("fadeout");
}
```

---

Though personally I wouldn't mix animation and coroutine. Rather use [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) and have a callback for when you are faded to black and from there do stuff and then trigger the fade back.